# MySQL WHERE With IF Condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause, conditional-statements

can anyone help me on why the WHERE clause if not functioning? And what is the alternative solution on it?

```
SELECT jq.jobid
  FROM jobqueue jq
  LEFT JOIN taskslogs tl
    ON jq.taskqueueid=tl.taskqueueid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT p1.taskID,p1.processingType
               FROM projecttask p
               LEFT JOIN projecttask p1
                 ON p.sequenceNo=p1.nextTaskSequence
                AND p.projectID=p1.projectID
              WHERE p.taskID=paramTaskID) prevTask
    ON tl.taskID=prevTask.taskID
 WHERE IF(prevTask.processingType='BATCH',jq.batchid!=0,IF(prevTask.processingType='DOCGROUP',jq.documentgroupid!=0,TRUE))
 GROUP BY jq.jobid
```

Comment: How is it not functioning? Errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
WHERE 
    (prevTask.processingType='BATCH' AND jq.batchid!=0)
    OR (prevTask.processingType='DOCGROUP' AND jq.documentgroupid!=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use IF statements in a query.  That is more for procedures.

You should probably look at using case statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html